# Apache CXF validation Error

Tags: soap, cxf

I am using apache cxf for soap client. When I make a soap call to the server, I get a `SoapFaultException` saying validation error from the library and there is no further information. Would anyone have any insight into what it could be?

Comment: Try to catch SoapFaultException and then log its stack trace. Maybe you get more information.

Comment: I did that but dont get any stack trace back. Which is pretty weird. Plus the message that I get back just says Validation Error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that the server was erroring out on an invalid request format and throwing a validation error which i think was wrapped up in the soap fault. Had to put loggingin interceptors in to get to that.

Thanks.